# Create choice column in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to create all the different types of column while a list is copied to other site collection. I got stuck with the choice column.

```
if (field.FieldTypeKind.ToString() == "Choice")
                                {
                                    string fieldSchema = "<Field Type='" + field.FieldTypeKind + "' DisplayName='" + field.Title + "' Name='" + field.InternalName + "' Hidden='" + field.Hidden + "'/>";

                                    targetcollField.AddFieldAsXml(fieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
                                    targetContext.Load(targetcollField);
                                    srcFieldCollections.Add(field);


                                }
```

It worked for other types of columns, is there anything extra needed for choice column.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code:

```
string schemaChoiceField = "<Field Type='Choice' DisplayName='Menu Choice' Name='MenuChoice'  
   Format='Dropdown' Hidden='FALSE'><Default>Pasta</Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>Pizza</CHOICE><CHOICE>Burger</CHOICE><CHOICE>Pasta</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>";
```

In your code, you are missing the `Format` value as well as the choice values.

If you dont want a dropdown, you can use Radio buttons as below:

```
string schemaChoiceField = "<Field Type='Choice' Name='DessertChoice' StaticName='DessertChoice' 
   DisplayName='Desserts' Format='RadioButtons'>"
   + "<Default>Ice cream</Default>"
   +         "<CHOICES>"
   +         "    <CHOICE>Fresh fruit</CHOICE>"
   +         "    <CHOICE>Sorbet</CHOICE>"
   +         "</CHOICES>"
   + "</Field>";
Field choiceField = demoList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(schemaChoiceField, true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
```

Also, if you want to use checkbox, use it as below:

```
string schemaChoiceField = "<Field ID='<GUID>' Type='MultiChoice' Name='SideDishesChoice' StaticName='SideDishesChoice' 
   DisplayName = 'Side dishes' >"
   + "<Default>Patatoes</Default>"
   +         "<CHOICES>"
   +         "    <CHOICE>Fresh vegetables</CHOICE>"
   +         "    <CHOICE>Beans</CHOICE>"
   +         "    <CHOICE>Pepper Sauce</CHOICE>"
   +         "</CHOICES>"
   + "</Field>";
Field choiceField = demoList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(schemaChoiceField, true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
```

Reference - [Creating fields using CSOM](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/creating-fields-using-csom/)

Comment: for static value this is working, but what if I need to get the choice column values from a choice column of other list. How can we do it in XML?

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying choices values which is required for field type choice., XML should be like below

```
<Field Type="Choice" Name="ApprovalStatus" DisplayName="Approval Status"><CHOICES><CHOICE>Pending</CHOICE><CHOICE>Approved</CHOICE><CHOICE>Reject‌​ed</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>
```